# Why Swagger Codegen is giving config class not load error when running from java?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen, openapi

I am trying to use Swagger Codegen from within java code to build an API automatically in spring like this:

```
String[] args = new String[4];
args[0] = "generate";
args[1] = "-i swagger.json";
args[2] = "-l spring";
args[3] = "-o output";
SwaggerCodegen.main(args);
```

Where, swagger is a valid json file, I used it in swagger editor UI and was able to generate the APIs perfectly. Also, SwaggerCodegen is imported from swagger-codegen-cli.jar (`import io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen;`), added as external jar dependency.

But, when I run this, I am getting the error as "Can't load config class with name spring", or for that matter any language. Tried to follow few suggestions like changing to latest version of cli jar etc, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this following for spring when using an IDE to run:

```
generate
-g spring
-i swagger.json
-o output
```